# Laravel Get created_at in Millisecond Timestamp

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1, unix-timestamp

In Laravel 5.1, I am trying to get the `created_at` date in millisecond timestamp to use in frontend javascript. How can I do that? My query at the moment is something like this:

```
$stats = User::where('created_at', '>=', $range)
               ->groupBy('date')
               ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
               ->get([
                      DB::raw('Date(created_at) as date'),
                      DB::raw('COUNT(*) as value')
                    ])
               ->toJSON();
```

I want the output of `created_at` to be like this: `1325356200000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are fine with using `DB::raw` you could try something like `DB::raw("CONCAT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(created_at)), '000000') as date")`.

Comment: thank you @svmm I am getting sql syntax error violation saying `UNIXTIMESTAMP does not exists`. And is there a way to do the same wiithout using `DB:raw` using pure Eloquent method?

Comment: sorry, it is `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Thats perfect. It works! Thank you @svmm. Can I do similar thing without `DB::raw`. I thought `DB::raw` was the easiest way to do this, am I right in thinking so?

Comment: You might be able to work with `->format()` provided by the carbon class.

Comment: I don't think you can solve your specific problem without `DB::raw`: You need to apply `date()` on your `created_at` column to have a working `groupBy`.

Comment: I wouldn’t suggest this method. Instead, select the timestamp from the database as normal. You’ll get a `Carbon` instance, from which you can get the millisecond timestamp from. Reduces the load on your database server this way.

Comment: Hi @MartinBean Thats interesting. Do you mean by just selecting the `created_by` via simple get() and then have a php foreach loop to convert the `created_by` to timestamp using Carbon? Or am I thinking it the wrong way?

Comment: @Neel `created_at` will come back as a `Carbon` instance any way if you’re using Eloquent. No need for raw queries.

Answer (score 3):

@Neel as you're using Laravel, you already have a great tool called [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) for working with PHP [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) Class. There is no need to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` for your purpose and this is not a good idea.

As you can find in [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) that `created_at` and `updated_at` are by default Carbon instances. So you can get timestamp like this and also [much more](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters)

```
User::findOrFail($id)->created_at->timestamp
```

If you get

```
"created_at" => "2015-10-07 06:10:49"
```

The result will produce a timestamp using the query above like this `1444198249`

After that you can manipulate your result as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for the `created_at` field and convert the datetime to a timestamp.

Comment: …And that will then break everywhere else `created_at` is used and expected to be a `Carbon` instance.

Comment: @MartinBean I don't think @JackPoint meant overriding the "created_at" accessor, just defining a new one, e.g. `public function getCreatedAtMilsAttribute()`